# How to convert a java application to an executable file?

Tags: java, javafx, launch4j

I'm using Launch4j to create my .exe file, when I apply the conversion method to a java project with only one package, it works, but once I gather so many projects in one main project with many packages, it creates the .exe file, but it doesn't work at all, the .jre works perfectly though.

What is the solution to make the main project's. exe file works?

Answer (score 0):

why not try pack a jar file.

it is available to pack multi class files to a jar.

then you can double click or call to use it.

**https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html**

Comment: can you be more explicit, i still didn't get how to solve that problem !

Comment: What you need? you have to tell more about the problem. 
In java toturial, it should have enough informations about creating jar and how to use it.

Comment: i have a project with one package, and i can convert it to an exe file using launch4j and it works, however, when i try to convert another project with many packages and many classes, launch4j creates the .exe file, but when double clicked, nothing happens, what is the problem ?

Comment: well, I never use launch4j. So if you want to use launch4j to create .exe file, I can't help more.  My suggestion for you is to create a .jar file, because it is the executable file type for java code.